# How do I make tags required with django-tagging?

Tags: python, django, django-tagging

I am using django-tagging to manage tags on my entities. How do I ensure that the user has entered at least one tag when filling out a form, other than using javascript validation on the front end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Are you using the TagField()? If so, [it extends the default Django CharField](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/tagging/forms.py#26) which accepts a `required=True` argument.</strike>

The above applies to a FormField, not ModelField. You can do this instead to make sure the Model field is always required in any subsequent form:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    tags = TagField(blank=False)
```

Comment: When I tried that I got: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'`

Comment: Apologies, my answer was referring to a FormField, not a ModelField. I've updated it.

Comment: @pastylegs: I also wanted to do the same thing but the issue is that if a user keeps the tag field blank then `form.errors` does not say that this field is required, it only rejects the form without any error message. I can do this using js but how can I show a `form.error` for `tagField ` using `blank=False`